# WordPress Custom Search by post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, search, page-template

I've tried a couple of methods but I cannot seem to filter custom post_types from my search results and was hoping someone could help.

I have installed "Job Manager" and created 4 jobs which have a custom `post_type = 'jobman_job'`

I tried to create a manual search form and set a hidden value of `post_type = jobman_job` but it still returned all posts.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="jobman_job" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I then tried creating a custom search page and redirecting the search to this page as follows (i.e added page_id hidden field):

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="jobman_job" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

And then in the custom search page, I added the following code (as per wordpress guide - http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) and I added the post_type of jobman_job to the query array:

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array('post_type' => 'jobman_job');

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
```

And it still displays all posts...

What am I doing wrong? I have checked the post_type column in the wp_posts table and I have 4 unique entries...so they are there...

Any Insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT TESTED!

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
$post_type = $_GET['type'];
if (!$post_type) {
    $post_type = 'jobman_job';
}
if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
};
return $query;
};

 add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

Comment: The only difference appears to be that you've made the value a select value instead of a hidden value - still gives the same result - shows all posts regardless of type...

Comment: just edited the answer... worked perfect for me

Comment: Ok... That works but it works across all searches! I am trying to have a custom search on the /jobs page that only searches for jobman_job post_type's - every other search should search all posts...

Comment: use the form I typed before, and then make a conditional that display this code if post_type, or maybe create an extra search class and call it in the action of your form... I don't see ur escenario so I cannot be that helpful :)

Comment: Working now - I copied search.php to job-search.php...Changed the form action to /job-search.php...Added your code above and it is now working as expected

Comment: way to go :)! glad it worked

Comment: didn't actually work... I hadn't removed the code from search.php so it was showing the right results but using search.php...

Comment: do you have others post type? or just looking to display post and pages?

Comment: I have installed the Job Manager plugin.  It creates a page on /jobs.  from this page, I want to search only post_types = jobman_job.  I am not using pages for anything else at the moment but can't say that will always be the case.

Comment: I think that function can help you, if not, I'm done =(